# VMWare Fusion Folder Sharing Not Working with Server

Tags: vmware, mac, file-sharing

I have a Ubuntu Server running in VMWare Fusion 3.1.2 on my MacBook Pro for Java development and all my projects sit on my Mac in ~/Workspace/ColdFusion. I had ColdFusion/ shared with my VM through the VMWare tools, and it was working perfectly up until friday when the folder sharing just stopped. No updates on either mac or linux besides an iTunes update. I tried uninstalling the VMWare tools and reinstalling them but I get an error at the end of the install. It appears that when I reinstall the tools there are files left over from the old installation. Is there a way to force the unsinstall script to completely uninstall and remove all files for the VMWare-Tools?

I know the shared folder used to mount at /mnt/hgfs/ColdFusion.

Comment: Sorry, no answer really. Just to mention that I hae the same problem.
Running Kubuntu 10.04 in VMWare Fusion 3.1.3 on a Mac OS X Snow Loepard.
Suddenly, after booting up in the morning, a folder shared from the mac
to the vm (linux) stopped working. The only thing I can think of that
might be the cause is the installation of nfs-kernel-server on the vm. Looking further for hints.

Comment: Dave I suggest that this is not the right place for this. You might have more luck on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com (both sister sites of Ask Ubuntu). I'll leave this open for now (in case this is Ubuntu's fault and somebody knows a fix) but if you do post it somewhere else and get an answer, please come back here and update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem running Kubuntu 10.04 in VMWare Fusion 3.1.3 on a Mac OS X Snow Leopard. Suddenly, after booting up in the morning, a folder, shared from the mac to the vm (linux), stopped working. The only thing I could think of the possible cause was the installation of nfs-kernel-server on the vm.

For me it worked to:

- Shut donw the virtual machine (Linux)
- Disable the share in Fusion.
- Disable sharing in Fusion.
- Boot and shut down the vm again (most likely a superfluous step).
- Enable sharing and recreate the share.
- Boot the vm.
- Reinstall VmWareTools (this step does really does it).

Now the share was availble again and nfs server still worked too.
And after rebooting the vm, all still worked ok.